# Python don't see a change in file

Tags: python, file, compiled, pyc

I have a python script that import a module that read a file and extract some information from it. This is like this:

```
import my_module
information = my_module.get_file_info(file_name)
print information.info1()
```

The module do:

```
class get_file_info():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def file_lines(self):
        file_to_get_info = open(self.file_name, 'r')
        lines = file_to_get_info.readlines()
        file_to_get_info.close()
        return lines

    def info1(self):
        info1 = do_something(self.file_lines())
        return info1
```

The variable 'file_name' is a text file and this is NOT edited by script. When I edit the text file, my class don't see the changes in first time I run the script (like the txt file is not edited), only the second time. What's wrong?

Additional information: I call the main python script from a batch file in windows and I thought it was problem with the pyc files, so I use the "-B" parameter:

```
python -B main_script.py
```

I deleted all pyc files and my main python script also import the sys module and has a "sys.dont_write_bytecode = True", but the problem still happens.

Comment: I don' quite understand your problem, but your `get_file_info` class seems not defined / coded properly. See [here](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html) for a tutorial and the use of `self.` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't put the `self.` here, there is no function "define_something(lines)", just the `self.` in sequence. But do something like:
`for line in lines:
    if 'string' in line: info1 = line
self.info1 = info1`

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why is your method name and class name same? And why are you taking self.lines as a parameter in your method. Please correct your code. It won't run.

Comment: and where are you passing your parameter "filename"? You want it to go to the class contsructor or to the method itself? Is that an error?

Comment: Indeed, I edited the question with many code errors. Sorry. Now it looks like my real code. The file name is for class constructor.

Comment: I found my error. My txt file is copied by script and I create the class object before the copy. So, the old file, before the copy, is still there when I run the script.